# Taskbar tooltip/popup label to show file location

Tags: popup, tooltip, toolbar, windows-10-desktop

I have several visual studios projects that are branches of each other. This means, that the file, in every branch, will always be "xyz.sln".

I'm trying to pin several different branches' solution file to my Visual Studio icon in the windows taskbar. When my colleague does this, and he hovers over the icon, it shows the location of the shortcut, and from that he knows which one to click. When I do this, it doesn't show any information about the location.

We cant' find any obvious setting to enable/disable this, but we have different build numbers for windows, where mine is newer.

Is this a removed feature? Is there any way to enable/bring back this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have pined Visual Studio icon on the task bar. **Right click** the icon display more detail about **Visual Studio** task. And you could pin the solution where in the recent. U could also drag the `sln` file to the taskbar and it will merge to Visual Studio detail automatically.

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure with your instructions you're giving. My VS is pinned to the TB, and I have several solutions pinned inside the VS icon, similar to your example above. When I right click any of the solutions, it gives me options to Open and Unpin, but nothing about more detail. However, after playing around now, I discovered that when I pin something new, it starts displaying the file locations,until I collapse the menu. If open the pinned items menu, it's gone again, only to appear when I pin something.

Comment: The solution does not dismiss after opened in my side. I don't really understand what the mean of *only to appear when I pin something*.

Comment: I Wish I could show with a screenshot. I'll try explain again. When I right click the VS icon, the context menu (like above) comes up, showing all my recent and 
 pinned solutions. When I hover over a link/solution, it does nothing. Then, when I pin or unpin something, and THEN hover over a link/solution, it displays the address of the file. @NIcoZhuMSFT

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue in my side. May the  location of solution was changed.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, no. The solution is still in the same location. As mentioned, it works the moment I pin/unpin anything in the context menu.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew. No, it did not answer my question.

Comment: But in my side it always work even if pined or unpinded item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173605/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-wyndiesel).

Comment: @WynDiesel, Have you tested this in other compture?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew. Yes, I have. It works at my colleague that is sitting next to me. When I do it there, it works (without any tinkering or fiddling), when I do it on mine, it doesn't. Either there is a feature I need to enable (hence my question here), or there is a bug in Windows.

Comment: There is no setting option for this feature, If it works in other compute, you could  check  your hard disk or tried to reinstall your operation system.

Comment: I strongly doubt that a problem with my hard disk would cause this to happen.

Comment: And NotePad has same feature within taskbar, could you test it?